# Separating components in multiples files and packages in Go

Tags: go

In my original code everything is defined in package main. I want to have the definition of the rest API in another package called `handlers`.

I'm my original code I have this

```
package main

type App struct {
    Router *mux.Router
    DB     *sql.DB
}

func main() {

    a.Router = mux.NewRouter()
    s := a.Router.PathPrefix("/api/v1").Subrouter()
    s.HandleFunc("/something", a.getSomething).Methods("GET")
}

func (a *App) getSomething(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    ...
}
```

I want to define all the handlers like `getSomething` on another package. Yet I also need access to `App` because of the DB object.

Is this achievable? Or is there another better way to do this?

The goal is to have something similar to this structure:

```
model (logic and db handling)
handlers (api handlers and calls to the model)
main.go (router config)
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access to names exported in the main package from other packages. Main package usually initializes everything used in the subsystems and passes those down. So, one way of doing what you need to do is to get rid of the App struct, initialize components in main, and pass those down to individual packages.

For DB, you might want to set a package-level variable in the packages that use DB, or pass it down to functions you call in that package, which then will pass it down to other functions.

For the router, you might want to setup the router in a package itself instead of setting it up in main, and get the router from the package so you can pass it to other packages that need it. For instance, you can have a `handlers.SetupRouter()` function that initializes the router and returns it, so you can have it in `main` to pass to other packages.

You can also do it as you're doing now: setup the router in main. Then you can set a package level variable under handlers package and use that.